# Can I use two AD623 instrumentation amps on one shunt to cover broader current range?

Tags: adc, instrumentation-amplifier, shunt

I'm working on building a circuit with an ESP8266 module.  I'd like to track its current consumption over time so I've cooked up a scheme to use a microcontroller dev board (Arduino or something similar) with an ADC to log the current consumption as it transitions from awake to deep sleep and back.

The problem is my current consumption ranges from 100uA in deep sleep to 100mA when it's awake and transmitting.  I was thinking about adding a 1 ohm resistor as a shunt between the power supply and the device and then using 2 [AD623](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ad623-1605360.pdf) instrumentation amps as inputs to the ADC.

I have two basic questions.  Is it reasonable to take two measurements from the same shunt?  Will that dramatically impact my measurements?

And, if the amp is saturated, will it just output the max voltage or will I damage the ic?

Here's something along the lines of what I'm thinking (one AD623 with a 11 kOhm RG for the 10x gain for sensing the mA range and the other with a 100 ohm RG for the 1000x gain for the uA range):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frFl69.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*I used labels to keep the schematic clean.  Not sure if that's cool or not . . . but that's what I did. :)*

This whole thing may be a little bit crazy town, but what I'm thinking is that if I use the Arduino internal 1.1V reference on the ADC and a 1000x gain, I should still get decent granularity in the uA range.  Basically, 1.1V / 1023 is a little under .0011V and with the 1000x gain my sensitivity should be roughly 1.1 uA.  I think I should be able to read between 0 uA and a little over 1000 uA.  I dunno if any of that is right but at least that's my current (no pun intended) rationale.

Comment: There are two ADC outputs from two AD623s wired together (yes that can work) but you haven't said where to connect or how to connect the two outputs.

Comment: Fair.  I was going to draw the other AD623 but CircuitLab wouldn't let me copy/paste and I was being lazy.  I'll be less lazy and fill out the rest of the circuit. :)

Comment: No need to just explain where it goes to see that you understand what needs to be done (I mean of course I know, but you need to show that to make your question complete)

Comment: Oh!!  I misunderstood.  Lemme make that clearer.  Also, what I think you thought I meant is quite clever.  I never thought about that.

Comment: OK.  I indicated that the two outputs were going to two separate analog input pins.

Comment: Yeah that should work OK but you might need a split rail supply.

Comment: Right on.  Thanks!  Why would I need a split rail supply?

Comment: If you are trying to measure AC currents greater than around 110 mA RMS. If you are measuring DC then you'll be fine but, if there's any chance you might get the inputs misplaced, it's probably a good idea to use 1 k series resistors.